# Repeatable installs of a Go application?

Tags: node.js, git, go, deployment

I am from the NodeJS/JavaScript world where I have `npm` and dependencies written down in the `package.json`. When I deploy it, I know that I just need to run `npm install` and all the dependencies consumed by the app will be installed.

How is it supposed to be done for a Go project? Suppose I have a source code of the app which I deploy remotely by, say, running `git pull`. Now, how do I make sure the dependencies are present? What I see is I need to install a package manager manually then install dependencies using it?

What's a standard way of deploying a Go app on a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're indeed thinking like a JS developer. Go is compiled, and thus the proper way to deploy a Go app is not to use the source code at all - you build it on your build server, and deploy a binary. So on the server level you simply don't care anymore, the only place where you need dependencies is the build system.

Now, the standard way to do this in go is to *vendor* dependencies with your source, that is make sure they are included in the git repo. Another approach is the express them in a manifest file and fetch them with an external tool. These are both more reliable than the naive approach, of simply using `go get` in build time, fetching the current version of your dependencies (this requires no manifest file).

There are many tools for vendoring management, to name two: [Godep](https://github.com/tools/godep) and [gb](http://dave.cheney.net/2016/06/26/automatically-fetch-your-projects-dependencies-with-gb)